# Unable to use axios post request response outside of function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, use-state

Using React & Axios. My post request response is an array of arrays, the second element of nested array is string I am trying to load onto a div through using map. Error is 'undefined is not iterable' I am trying to use useState to use the array outside of post request. The entire section opens with useState via a button and by default is closed/not loaded. There is also a user input which the post request uses to get it data, all of that works fine. I am just unable to map the string from the array into a div. I tried to use window.var to access it but this was unsuccessful as well. Appreciate any help!

```
import './Turnersdiscoverybody.css'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Turnershomenav from "../../../components/homepage/homepage-components/Turnershomenav.js";
import orangegtr1 from './turnersdiscovery-images/orangegtr-1.jpg'
import searchicon from './turnersdiscovery-images/searchicon.png'
export default function Turnersdiscoverybody() {


    const [showSearchForm, setShowSearchForm] = useState('noForm')
    const [input, setInput] = useState['']
    //functions for opening and closing search feature

    const handleClick = () => {
        setShowSearchForm('showForm')
    }
    const handleClickBack = () => {
        setShowSearchForm('noForm')
    }


    //axios post request starts

    //function that handles searching the documents with the user input, using axios

    const handleSearch = (e) => {
        let userQuery = document.getElementById('userInput').value

        e.preventDefault()
        axios.post(`http://localhost:8081/getDocumentdata/${userQuery}`)
            .then(res => {
                setInput(res.data)
                console.log(res.data)
            })

    }


    //axios post request ends

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="turnersdiscoverynav">
                <Turnershomenav />
            </div>
            <div className='backgroundimg-container'>
                <img src={orangegtr1} alt="background-img" className='turnersdiscovery-backgroundimg'></img>
            </div>
            {showSearchForm === 'showForm' &&
                <>
                    <img className="img-btn-search" alt="search icon" src={searchicon} onClick={handleClickBack}></img>
                    <div className='form-search-container'>
                        <div className='form-search-container-top'>
                            <input
                                id="userInput"
                                required
                                type="text"
                                placeholder='enter your query'
                            ></input>
                            <button onClick={handleSearch}>hello click me for stuff</button>
                        </div>

                        <div className='form-search-container-bottom'>
                            <div className='form-search-container-bottom-content'>
                                {input.map((data) => (
                                    <div>{data[1]}</div>
                                )
                                )}
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </>
            }
            {showSearchForm === "noForm" && <img className="img-btn-search" alt="search icon" src={searchicon} onClick={handleClick}></img>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors in your code:

```
//1 => const [input, setInput] = useState([])
//2 => check if inputs is not empty then map!
```

Now your code must be like this:

```
export default function Turnersdiscoverybody() {
const [showSearchForm, setShowSearchForm] = useState('noForm')
const [input, setInput] = useState([]);
const [empty, setEmpty] = useState(false);
//functions for opening and closing search feature
const handleClick = () => {
    setShowSearchForm('showForm')
}
const handleClickBack = () => {
    setShowSearchForm('noForm')
}


//axios post request starts

//function that handles searching the documents with the user input, using axios

const handleSearch = (e) => {
    let userQuery = document.getElementById('userInput').value
    e.preventDefault()
    axios.post(`http://localhost:8081/getDocumentdata/${userQuery}`)
        .then(res => {
            if(res && res.length > 0){
             setInput(res.data)
             setEmpty(false)
             }else{
              setEmpty(true)
              }
            console.log(res.data)
        })

}

return (
    <div>
        <div className="turnersdiscoverynav">
            <Turnershomenav />
        </div>
        <div className='backgroundimg-container'>
            <img src={orangegtr1} alt="background-img" 
 className='turnersdiscovery-backgroundimg'></img>
        </div>
        {showSearchForm === 'showForm' &&
            <>
                <img className="img-btn-search" alt="search icon" src={searchicon} onClick={handleClickBack}></img>
                <div className='form-search-container'>
                    <div className='form-search-container-top'>
                        <input
                            id="userInput"
                            required
                            type="text"
                            placeholder='enter your query'
                        ></input>
                        <button onClick={handleSearch}>hello click me for stuff</button>
                    </div>

                    <div className='form-search-container-bottom'>
                        <div className='form-search-container-bottom-content'>
                           {empty ? <p>Nothing Found </p> : 
                                 <>
                                                                 
                        {input.length > 0 && input.map((data, index) => (
                                <div>{data[1]}</div>
                            )
                            )}
                                </>
                             }
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </>
        }
        {showSearchForm === "noForm" && <img className="img-btn-search" alt="search icon" src={searchicon} onClick={handleClick}></img>}
    </div>
   )
 }
```

Comment: Im pretty new to hooks, thanks so much! I was going crazy

Comment: @coldharbour No problem, errors are for learning.

Comment: and yeah im trying to figure out how to load 'search returned nothing' if the input is empty

Comment: you can use another state.

    if(!userQuery ) => {
     setError('pleas fill the form!')
    }

Comment: the axios response is some an array right but if the user search cant find any documents it returns an empty list, which then gets mapped and nothing gets displayed. map seems like the only way to display the data but if there no data i dont know how to display 'search returns nothing' if i have to map in the first place

Comment: How does that enable me to load 'no results found' if the array is empty?

Comment: sorry for taking up your time haha. Now its loading 'Nothing Found' on every search

Comment: sorry you should check => res.data.length > 0

Comment: working as intended, appreciate your help man im gonna compare the code to better understand it. Have a good night!

Answer (score 0):

```
const [input, setInput] = useState['']
```

should be

```
const [input, setInput] = useState('')
```

P.s. if you run into more issues, a minimal code reproduction would be good, somewhere like codepen or codesandbox.

Comment: Thanks dude! really need to start using codepen.

Answer (score -2):

```
const [input, setInput] = useState['']
```

should have been

```
const [input, setInput] = useState([])
```

Comment: rip thought this would mark question as closed or something